# LDAP integration with Solr

Tags: security, solr, ldap, jetty

I am trying to integrate LDAP with Solr. I know it was possible with the old Solr 5 but we need LDAP authentication for Solr 7. Solr 7 now only comes with bare minimum Jetty and doesn't support LDAPLoginModule of Jetty. Does anyone know any Solr security LDAP plugin or anything?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the only support is through two commercial offerings, [Cloudera](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/cdh_sg_search_security.html#search_enable_ldap) and [Fusion](https://lucidworks.com/2016/03/23/secure-fusion-leveraging-ldap/).

Comment: Ok, Thanks. Didn't anybody tried it yet?